# Couldn't use gsheets flutter package

Tags: flutter, package, version, depends

I made a flutter app and named it gsheets to test gsheets package and when I tried to download the package it said "*Because gsheets depends on gsheets, version solving failed*".
After wasting about tow hours searching I tried to do it with an other project with another name and it worked.
I think packages won't work if the project has the same name, I hope this way help you and save your precious time.

I don't know why is this happening, If anyone knows why, please give us an idea.

Here is my terminal code:

```
PS G:\Flutter Apps\gsheets> flutter pub add gsheets
Because gsheets depends on gsheets, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Comment: Can you share your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/Ezzalarab/gsheets/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the project name is the same as the library name. So if you have the same Error as this just try to change the project name.